# i Have make a flutter app for news using getx controller and is working for getting post,category but when i try to use it for post detail it fails?

Tags: flutter

i Have make a flutter app for news using getx controller and is working for getting post,category but when i try to use it for post detail it fails?i dont know what i have to do now. Can you please help me.

This is my Controller file for post details

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:newstv/model/news_model.dart';
import 'package:newstv/services/api_services.dart';

class PostDetailController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var postModel = NewsModel().obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    fetchPostDetails();
  }

  Future<void> fetchPostDetails({postId = 1}) async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var postDetails =
          await APIService().fetchPostDetails(postId);
      // postsModel.addAll(posts);
      postModel.value = postDetails as NewsModel;
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my model file

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final newsModel = newsModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<NewsModel> newsModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<NewsModel>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => NewsModel.fromJson(x)));

String newsModelToJson(List<NewsModel> data) => json.encode(
    List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class NewsModel {
  String id;
  String title;
  String date;
  String author;
  String content;
  String image;
  String category;

  NewsModel({
    this.id = '1',
    this.title = '21',
    this.date = '11',
    this.author = '1',
    this.content = '1',
    this.image = '1',
    this.category = '1',
  });

  factory NewsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      NewsModel(
        id: json["ID"],
        title: json["TITLE"],
        date: json["DATE"],
        author: json["AUTHOR"],
        content: json["CONTENT"],
        image: json["IMAGE"],
        category: json["CATEGORY"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "ID": id,
        "TITLE": title,
        "DATE": date,
        "AUTHOR": author,
        "CONTENT": content,
        "IMAGE": image,
        "CATEGORY": category,
      };
}
```

This is my ui where i tried to  get the api data

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:newstv/controllers/postDetail_controller.dart';

import 'utills/Layout_utills.dart';

class NewsDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  NewsDetail({super.key});
  final PostDetailController newsdetailController =
      Get.put(PostDetailController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      newsdetailController.fetchPostDetails(
          postId: Get.arguments);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: BackgroundImage(),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
            expandedHeight: 250,
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Obx(() {
              if (newsdetailController.isLoading.value) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return NewsDetailed_Section();
              }
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

//----------image  section----------//
  Widget BackgroundImage() {
    return Obx(() {
      if (newsdetailController.isLoading.value) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        return Image.network(
          newsdetailController.postModel.value.image,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        );
      }
    });
  }

//==========details section===========///
  Widget NewsDetailed_Section() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Obx(() {
            if (newsdetailController.isLoading.value) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return Row1();
            }
          }),
          LayoutUtils.iconText(
            Icon(Icons.timer),
            Text(newsdetailController.postModel.value.date),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Text(newsdetailController.postModel.value.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.grey,
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            width: 100,
          ),
          Expanded(
            // child: Html(
            //     style: {"p": Style(color: Colors.black54)},
            //     data: '<p><b>api content</b></p>'))
            child: Text(newsdetailController
                .postModel.value.content),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget Row1() {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Text(
                newsdetailController
                    .postModel.value.category,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Row(children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: null,
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.moon),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: null,
                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bookmark),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

I have checked that the api is successfully called with reference id but it was not showing in ui .
i have also tried by adding the required on model but it will throw errors .i have tried in controller file but when i try to remove the  ''postModel.value = postDetails as NewsModel;'' as news model from above given it will throw error. Can yo please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your way of converting the response to your model is wrong.

you should write:

```
var postDetails =
      await APIService().fetchPostDetails(postId);
  // postsModel.addAll(posts);
  postModel.value = NewsModel.fromJson(postDetails.body);
```

Also the way you are calling the method **fetchPostDetails** in your controller is wrong, you should remove the call in the **onInit** method

or what is better
delete the **Future.delayed** in your build method and make your controller **onInit** like this:

```
@override 
void onInit() {
super.onInit();
var id=Get.arguments;
fetchPostDetails(postId:id);}
```